# Fix background div in asp.net

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have a relatively simple issue that I am trying to resolve. I am trying to fix a background div (`<div class="main-background">`) containing an image on the page. It appears in Design View in Visual Studio, but when I run the application, it does not show (or is being covered). The other controls do appear. What am I doing wrong here?

```
<div class="main-background">
  <div class="center">
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlOptions" runat="server" BackColor="#669999" HorizontalAlign="Center" Height="55px" Width="607px" BorderStyle="Double">
      <div style="vertical-align: top">
        <asp:Label ID="lblAvailableOptions" runat="server" Text="Available Options" Font-Size="X-Large" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Black" Font-Names="Trebuchet MS" Style="vertical-align: bottom"></asp:Label>
      </div>
    </asp:Panel>
  </div>
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <asp:Panel ID="pnlButtons" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center">
    <asp:Button ID="btnGroupSummary" runat="server" Text="Group Summary" CssClass="btn btn-mainmenu" OnClick="btnGroupSummary_Click" BackColor="#3D5C5C" /><br />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnServices" runat="server" Text="Services" CssClass="btn btn-mainmenu" BackColor="#527A7A" /><br />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnLetters" runat="server" Text="Letters" CssClass="btn btn-mainmenu" BackColor="#94B8B8" />
  </asp:Panel>
</div>
```

The div class "main-background" has the following CSS:

```
.main-background {
  background: url(../Images/main-background.JPG) center fixed;
  background-size: 800px, 800px, auto;
}
```

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Maybe the live page is in such a location that the path `../Images/main-background.JPG` is incorrect. Try using browser Developer Tools (Network tab) to see if a `404` occurs when loading the image.

Answer (score 0):

Change your css and add only "height: 800px;"

```css
.main-background {
  background: url(https://www.reneeaudubon.com/uploads/9/5/4/2/9542466/2748307_orig.jpg) center fixed;
  background-size: 800px, 800px, auto;    
  height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-background">
  <div class="center">
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlOptions" runat="server" BackColor="#669999" HorizontalAlign="Center" Height="55px" Width="607px" BorderStyle="Double">
      <div style="vertical-align: top">
        <asp:Label ID="lblAvailableOptions" runat="server" Text="Available Options" Font-Size="X-Large" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Black" Font-Names="Trebuchet MS" Style="vertical-align: bottom"></asp:Label>
      </div>
    </asp:Panel>
  </div>
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <asp:Panel ID="pnlButtons" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center">
    <asp:Button ID="btnGroupSummary" runat="server" Text="Group Summary" CssClass="btn btn-mainmenu" OnClick="btnGroupSummary_Click" BackColor="#3D5C5C" /><br />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnServices" runat="server" Text="Services" CssClass="btn btn-mainmenu" BackColor="#527A7A" /><br />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnLetters" runat="server" Text="Letters" CssClass="btn btn-mainmenu" BackColor="#94B8B8" />
  </asp:Panel>
</div>
```

image is referenced from https://www.reneeaudubon.com